# Using Reserved names with realm.io / Android

Tags: java, android, realm

Imagine there's an API that returns something like this:

```
       "names":{  
           "short":"xxx",
           "medium":null,
           "long":"xxxxxx"
        },
```

(just an example)

Then imagine that you have a model to represent the above that looks like this:

```
public class Names extends RealmObject {
   private String short;
   private String medium;
   private String long;
   // getters/setters omitted for clarity
}
```

There's a problem, since both `short` and `long` are reserved keywords in Java.

Other ORMs present an annotation (usually `@Key("othername")`) to deal with these scenarios.

What would be realm.io's solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. Our JSON support is still pretty simple, but we plan to address issues like those in the next iteration. Currently you have two options: Either convert the JSON to JSONObject and manually map the fields in a static methods like this:

```
public class Names extends RealmObject {

  ...

  public static Names fromJson(JSONObject json) {
    Names names = new Names();
    names.setShortField(json.getString("short");
    return names;
  }
}
```

or alternatively if you don't mind including other 3rd party libraries, you can use GSON which has a `@SerializedName` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Christian. Looking forwards for the next iteration (that will hopefully include Null support) ;)

Comment: @Christian Melchior It would be sweet if you guys could make an Annotation for it, like: @Row("abstract") 
private String abstractField; ....
By the way I'm having this issue right now to get the NewYorkTimes API JSON hahah.

Comment: Funny, I just had the same problem with their API as well and a field named  `abstract` :) ... We have it on our Roadmap, but right now the solution would be to use one of the available GSON mappers like GSON, Jackson or Moshi